# Flutter: Preventing size change to child widgets in GridView

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

I have code that uses `GridView` to create a list of items with number of columns based on devices orientation or width.

```dart
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: columnCount(context),
  childAspectRatio: 8.0,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
  mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
  children: <Widget>[...textsWidgets],
);
```

The problem is, the children (`textsWidgets`) changes size upon resizing the window of the application during runtime. Is there a way to prevent children from changing size when resizing the window of the application during runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use instead a wrap widget and use a sizedbox or a container as children and define the with and the height like this:

```
Wrap(
          spacing : 10.0,
          runSpacing : 10.0,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: Center(child: Text('data'))
            ),
            Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: Center(child: Text('data'))
            ),
            Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: Center(child: Text('data'))
            ),
            Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: Center(child: Text('data'))
            ),
            Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: Center(child: Text('data'))
            ),
            Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: Center(child: Text('data'))
            ),
            Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: Center(child: Text('data'))
            ),
            Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.indigo,
                child: Center(child: Text('data'))
            ),
          ],
        )
```

this is how it looks in small size window:

[image]

this is how it looks in big size window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap a GridView with ConstrainedBox to prevent it from growing with the window, like:

```dart
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 320),
  child: GridView.count(…),
)
```

Comment: This does not work.